# Extracting the coordinates associated with voxels from a text file and store in a .mat file

Tags: matlab, coordinates, extract

I have a text file formatted as follows:

```
FileVersion: 1


TimePoint:   1

NrOfROIs:    3

ROI:         1
NrOfVoxels:  7
 43  22   5    766
 45  22   5    837
 42  23   5    961
 43  23   5    878
 44  23   5    760
 43  24   5    889
 43  25   5    929
AvgValue: 860.000000

ROI:         2
NrOfVoxels:  7
 20  21   5    668
 22  21   5    727
 23  21   5    748
 24  21   5    727
 23  22   5    810
 23  23   5    868
 24  23   5    764
AvgValue: 759.000000
```

I have to extract the coordinates (only the first three columns) of voxels associated with every ROI and save them in a different .mat file, respectively. For example, after extracting the coordinates of ROI: 1, I should have the coordinates (first three colums) in a .mat file something like this (And for ROI 2 in a different .mat file):

```
 43 22 5
 45 22 5
 42 23 5
 43 23 5
 44 23 5
 43 24 5
 43 25 5
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve it using Matlab? I could only open the file and read line-by-line.

Here is the Matlab code, to read the coordinates associated only with the ROI 1:

```
filename = 'test.ert';
fid = fopen(filename);

r_lines = 9;
for k = 1:r_lines
    fgetl(fid);
end

elines = 7;
for i = 1:elines
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    tline = tline(:, 1:end-7);
disp(tline)
end

fclose(fid)
```

And, here is the output:

```
43  22   5
45  22   5
45  22   5
45  22   5
45  22   5
45  22   5
45  22   5
```

How do I save the output to .mat file?

Comment: Opening the file and reading line by line sounds like you're already taking the correct approach, can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `textread` function in the Matlab documentation. It is possible to read the text file in a formatted way, e.g. if you set the format to `'%u %u %u'`, the values that you need will be read. You can even store them in vectors if you want.